# Swift Datepicker with minimum date

Tags: ios, date, datepicker

Goord Morning all together,

i have an app with ios 8 and swift.
in there is a `UIViewcontroller` within a `UIDatepicker`

I set a minimum date. for example the date of today:  2 | May | 2015
with this solution it should not be possible to set a date which is in the past

but if would like to set this date  15 | January | 2016
i set at first the day to 15
than the month to january but then the `UIDatepicker` goes back to the minimum date 2 May 2015

is it be possible, that wenn change the day to 15 and the month to january, that the year changes automaticly to 2016?

Comment: set picker.minimumdate=[nsdate date];

Comment: this is not the solution for my problem ... the minimum date is set. the problem is, if i would like to set an date which is in the future, i have to select at first the year and than i can change day and month.

Comment: I don't believe what you are looking for is possible with the standard `UIDatePicker` control. You would have to implement something from scratch.

Comment: @Ghost108, were you able to implement the solution below?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let your minimumDate unset and try to configure it by code...

Try this:

```
@IBAction func changeValue(sender: UIDatePicker) 
{

    //Get time Now, and convert to a NSCalendar
    //Specify the minimun date if you want.
    let now = NSDate()
    let nowCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let nowComponents = nowCalendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: now)

    //Compare if date is lesser than now and then create a new date
    if nowCalendar.compareDate(sender.date, toDate: now, toUnitGranularity: [.Day, .Month, .Year]) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending
    {

        let dateCalendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let dateComponents = dateCalendar.components([.Day, .Month, .Year], fromDate: sender.date)

        dateComponents.year = nowComponents.year + 1
        let newDate = dateCalendar.dateFromComponents(dateComponents)
        sender.date = newDate!
    }

}
```

Comment: You can get more information at http://nshipster.com/nscalendar-additions/ and at http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/data-types/dates

Comment: Does this work now on Xcode 9 and Swift 3, @dede.exe ?

Comment: @Shyam You will need to do some changes to make this work in swift3

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, @dede.exe. I did go with another solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
///Swift4 Version - I think it may works with 3 too.
@IBAction func changeValue(sender: UIDatePicker)
{

    //Get time Now, and convert to a NSCalendar
    //Specify the minimun date if you want.
    let now = Date()
    let nowCalendar = Calendar.current
    let nowComponents = nowCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: now)

    //Compare if date is lesser than now and then create a new date
    if nowCalendar.compare(sender.date, to: now, toGranularity: Calendar.Component.day) == ComparisonResult.orderedAscending
    {
        var dateCalendar = Calendar.current
        var dateComponents = dateCalendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: sender.date)

        guard let year = nowComponents.year else { return }

        dateComponents.year = year + 1
        let newDate = dateCalendar.date(from:dateComponents)
        sender.date = newDate!
    }
}
```

I published a complete example working in playground if you wish to play a little.
https://gist.github.com/dedeexe/4878f78d7e1d5fe8b372ef84de629b59

Comment: I hope this example can help you @Shyam

Answer (score 0):

**For swift 4:**

I have like this. 
1. My function:

```
func AddDaysToToday(days: Int) -> Date? {
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.day = days

    return Func.GetCalendar(tz: .utc).date(byAdding: dateComponents, to: Date()) //you can return your own Date here.
}
```

2. In my VC:

   ```
   let today = DateFunc.AddDaysToToday(days: 0)
   datePicker.minimumDate = today
   ```